# Partially ordered sets that has maximal element but no last element

Tags: order-theory

I'm trying to understand the idea behind partially ordered sets. I'm trying to think of a simple example of a partially ordered set that has a one maximum element but no last element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to guess at what idea you have in mind... consider the set whose elements are the natural numbers together with an extra element called $*$. Extend the usual ordering on the natural numbers by:

- $* \leq *$ is true
- $* \leq n$ and $n \leq *$ are both false for every natural number $n$

This partial order has two features:

- $*$ is the only maximal element, but it is not a maximum
- The collection of natural numbers is an increasing chain without an upper bound

Answer (score 0):

If you have $A=\{1,2,4,8,10\}$ with ordinary divisibility $\mid$ then $8$ is maximal element in $A$ but not last element. Also $10$ is maximal element. If we have $B=\{1,2,4,8\}$ then 8 is maximal and last element. Last element is always the maximal element (if exist) but not vice versa. Last element is therefore unique and maximal are not necessary unique.

Comment: In the first example, $8$ is the maximal element because $8$ can be divided by $1,2,4,8$?

Comment: @kickstart: 8 is maximal because it doesn't divide anything else. (10 is also maximal)